# No puedi iniciar sesión en Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, microsoft

Descargué VIsual Studio 2017 Community. Tengo entendido que el IDE se desbloquea iniciando sesión con una cuenta de Microsoft, sin embargo no puedo iniciar sesión, las únicas opciones que tengo son iniciar sesión o cerrar Visual Studio ya que el periodo de prueba de 30 días finalizó
Cuando trato de iniciar sesión se cuelga en esa ventana cargando y al final me tira ese error, no se como hacer!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo hacer click en ningún lugar fuera de esta ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo presente el mismo problema al instalar Visual Studio 2017. Lo que hice fue ingresar con un correo de dominio @hotmail y con el cual tengo iniciados todos los servicios en mi computadora. La primera vez que ingrese el correo me marco un error y se pasmo la pantalla por lo cual que tuve que reiniciar el programa. Después cuando intentente ingresar el correo tardo un poco en sincronizarse pero me permitio acceder sin problema. No se si funcione con correos con dominio @outlook o algún otro, pero con @hotmail si funciona.

Comment: Yo tengo un correo con domino @hotmail pero es ".es" no se si tendrá algo que ver, voy a probar creando otra cuenta de correo con .com